# How to save a variable to an array every time a while loop runs?

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

I want to save the result of my while loop every time it runs to an array. Then once all conversions have been run, the array that stores all the values will be summed.

```py
raw_user_age = input("Number: ")

x = int(raw_user_age)

g=0

while g < x :
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        
        YOUR_ACCESS_KEY = ''
        url = 'https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD'
        c = Currency_convertor(url)
        from_country = input("From Country: ")
        to_country = input("TO Country: ")
        amount = int(input("Amount: "))
        
        returnedamount=c.convert(from_country, to_country, amount)
        g += 1
        print(returnedamount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your array before the beginning of the loop:

```
values_returned = []
```

You can use the `append` method to add an element to the array every time the loop runs:

```
values_returned.append(returnedamount)
```

After the loop is done, you can use the `sum()` function to get the sum of all values in the array:

```
sum(values_returned)
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much this will make life much easier.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: When I ran the sum(values_returned) command and then print(values_returned) it didn't return the sum of the 2 values rather it printed both values instead of their sum. How do I fix this?

Comment: `sum(values_returned)` **returns** the sum, so you would have to rather `print(sum(values_returned))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append the value to the array (list) like so:

```
list_ = []

value1 = 1
value2 = 2

list_.append(value1)
list_.append(value2)
```

Comment: To get the sum of the `list_` just use the in-built function [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: Where exactly would I put this in terms of the code? and what should I change value1 or value 2 to for it to append.